# VGA input format

Tags: video, image-processing, input, vga

How could you get coordinates (x,y) of pixel colors in VGA format (from a vga cable)? I know pins 13 and 14 are horizontal & vertical sync, so how would I use that to get the coordinates of the rgb obtained from the first 3 pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VGA, as per [DE-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature#Computer_video_output) and similar output channels is [*analog*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_video#Analog_video)<sup>1</sup>.

There is no trivial way to "read" a pixel at a specific coordinate - when going directly to an analog CRT there weren't even "x/y pixel coordinates" assigned by the device! It was only with the advent of later LCD monitors that the VGA analog signal was converted back into a digital (i.e. "with coordinates") format prior to being displayed.

One way to solve this problem/task is to use an analog [*frame grabber*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_grabber) card/device and access the digitized image stream.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [VGA Video Signal Format and Timing Specifications](http://www.javiervalcarce.eu/wiki/VGA_Video_Signal_Format_and_Timing_Specifications) for a brief overview of the analog format.